# Call a Method which has params using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to call a method that has Params using reflection. It is returning System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException

This is happening only to the methods which have params keyword in method parameters

```
Public static dynamic Function(JObject data, string PathFunction) {            

        string MethodName = "MergeFields";
        string FunctionsNamespace ="Test.Functions";

        Object[] parameterArray = {"274-84-3068","5","1","Hugenberg","4","0"}

        // Call Static class functions 
        Type type = Type.GetType(FunctionsNamespace);            
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);            
        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(MethodName);            
        object st =  methodInfo.Invoke(obj, parameterArray);
        return st;

    }



     public static string MergeFields(params string[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       // code to be processed
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got a method:

```
public static string MergeFields(params string[] data)
```

and you call:

```
MergeFields("a", "b", "c");
```

the compiler secretly turns that into:

```
MergeFields(new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });
```

However when you're using reflection, you don't get the compiler's help here! You'll need to create that string array yourself:

```
object[] parameterArray = new object[] { new string[] { "274-84-3068", "5", "1", "Hugenberg", "4", "0" } };
```

Here we are going to pass a single parameter to `MergeFields`, and that parameter is an array of strings.